How to Fix Layout Issues with Keyboard Appearance During SwiftUI Screen Navigation?
I have a SwiftUI app that uses a legacy text field (UIKit one) and performs navigations with HostViewController. Here is the major issue I am facing:
I am pushing a screen onto the current screen, and the second screen should have the keyboard appear when it comes up. Whenever the second screen is presented with the keyboard, if the first screen is still not fully dismissed and is presenting the keyboard, it causes a layout issue on the previous screen. It changes the bottom safe area for both screens. Adding a delay for the keyboard appearance solves the issue, but that's not a real solution.
example of my textField
import SwiftUI
import UIKit

extension TextField {
    struct LegacyTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
        @Environment(\.disableAutocorrection) private var disableAutocorrection
        @Environment(\.keyboardType) private var keyboardType
        @Environment(\.textInputAutocapitalization) private var textInputAutocapitalization
        @Environment(\.returnKeyType) private var returnKeyType

        @Binding var isEditing: Bool
        @Binding var text: String

        private let onCommit: () -> Bool
        private let formattingBlock: (String) -> String
        private let configuration: ((UITextField) -> Void)?

        init(
            text: Binding<String>,
            isEditing: Binding<Bool>,
            onCommit: @escaping () -> Bool,
            formattingBlock: @escaping (String) -> String,
            configuration: ((UITextField) -> Void)? = nil
        ) {
            self._text = text
            self._isEditing = isEditing
            self.onCommit = onCommit
            self.formattingBlock = formattingBlock
            self.configuration = configuration
        }

        func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
            let textField = UITextField()
            textField.delegate = context.coordinator
            textField.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.textFieldDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
            updateViewProperties(textField)
            return textField
        }

        func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
            context.coordinator.parent = self

            if uiView.text != text {
                uiView.text = text
            }
            updateViewProperties(uiView)

            // Handle first responder status based on isEditing
            if isEditing && !uiView.isFirstResponder {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
                }
            } else if !isEditing && uiView.isFirstResponder {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    uiView.resignFirstResponder()
                }
            }
        }

        func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
            Coordinator(self)
        }

        private func updateViewProperties(_ uiView: UITextField) {
            if let disableAutocorrection = disableAutocorrection {
                uiView.autocorrectionType = disableAutocorrection ? .no : .yes
            }
            uiView.keyboardType = keyboardType
            uiView.returnKeyType = returnKeyType
            uiView.autocapitalizationType = textInputAutocapitalization
            uiView.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
            uiView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
            configuration?(uiView)
        }

        final class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
            var parent: LegacyTextField

            init(_ parent: LegacyTextField) {
                self.parent = parent
                super.init()
                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleViewDisappear), name: UIApplication.willResignActiveNotification, object: nil)
            }
            
            deinit {
                NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
            }

            @objc func textFieldDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
                guard let text = textField.text else {
                    parent.text = ""
                    return
                }
                let formattedText = parent.formattingBlock(text)
                if textField.text != formattedText {
                    textField.text = formattedText
                }
                if parent.text != formattedText {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.parent.text = formattedText
                    }
                }
            }

            func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
                if !parent.isEditing {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.parent.isEditing = true
                    }
                }
            }

            func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
                if parent.isEditing {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.parent.isEditing = false
                    }
                }
            }

            func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
                if parent.onCommit() {
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                        textField.resignFirstResponder()
                    }
                    return true
                }
                return false
            }

            @objc func handleViewDisappear() {
                if parent.isEditing {
                    parent.isEditing = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


I have tried to add a delay to the uiView.becomeFirstResponder() method. It's helping, but I think we should find a better solution.

Did you find a solution to this?
